# localStorage.setItem() At least 2 arguments required but only 1 passed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to create a simple quest tracker in React, I want the checked value of true to persist in localStorage, but I'm getting this error. I understand that the arguments can only be strings so I tried JSON.stringify the boolean value but it still returns 1 argument. Here is the checkbox I've mapped to each quest in an array.

```
{props.mainQuests.map((quest, i) => {
    return (
        <div className="questlist">
            <li key={quest} className="quest">
                <p className="questName">{quest}</p>
                <p className="questDesc">{mainQuestDesc[i]}</p>
                <label for="completed">Completed</label>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="completed"
                  id={quest}
                  onChange={props.toggleCheckboxChange}
                  autoComplete="off"
                ></input>
            </li>
        </div>
          );
```

And here is the function declared in the App.js component.

```
toggleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.type === "checkbox") {
        const current = JSON.stringify(e.target.checked);
        console.log(e.target.id);
        console.log(current);
        localStorage.setItem({ [e.target.id]: current });
    }
  };
```

Both the console logs return string values, so I'm quite confused, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `localStorage.setItem({ [e.target.id]: current });` why did you want to pass one argument here? could have done `localStorage.setItem(e.target.id,  current);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to set a `localStorage` value, the first one being:

```
localStorage.setItem(e.target.id, current);
```

and the second one, perhaps even simpler:

```
localStorage[e.target.id] = current;
```

For more examples, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

And a note of interest, I see you are already doing this so that's good: `localStorage` will convert every value that is not a string by first doing *`.toString()`* on the value. As a result it is best to use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to store numbers, booleans, arrays and objects; and use `let obj = JSON.parse(valueFromLocalStorage)` to retrieve them again, which works for all object types.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the Documentation yes localstorage need to pass string as a value but it's also need key check this [localstorage example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#example)
in your case your have to pass it like this it's just a sentax error try this below

```
localStorage.setItem(e.target.id , current );
```

> localStorage.setItem(key , stringValue);